# geometry nodes extrude

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I want to use Blender's new Geometry Nodes in version 3.0 to create a solid between upper inclined body and lower plane surface.

If an extrude operation of a plane was available, I would create a body by 1) create a plane out of the 4 vertices marked on image 2) extrude that plane downwards onto lower plane surface.

However, extrude is not available in 3.0. Any ideas to a workaround?

[image: Geometries]

Comment: I have a feeling that the Raycast node might be part of the solution somehow

Comment: You can use curve nodes to create a "plane" that can be extruded. Is something like that  what you are after?

Comment: @Timaroberts: can u show how that works? i tried...but failed. i can do this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2UTe.png, but if i use transform on z axis...nothing happened: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/65OyF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Blender 3.1** has a new *extrude* geometry node.

Here is the documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/extrude_mesh.html

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure it's exactly what you want, and it is a workaround, but you can use a [curve line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve_primitives/curve_line.html#curve-line-node) and [quadrilateral node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve_primitives/quadrilateral.html#quadrilateral-node) to create a plane that can be extruded.

Using the *[Curve to mesh node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/curve_to_mesh.html#curve-to-mesh-node)*, add the quadrilateral as the profile curve of the line.
Changing the end point of the line on the $Z$ axis here will control the depth of extrusion.

The [set shade smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/set_shade_smooth.html#set-shade-smooth-node) with shade smooth unticked is only to shade the object flat, it is optional.

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>
[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>